# how to add animation on bootstrap Tooltip?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way to add slide down animation on bootstrap tooltip, when hover.

`<img src="assets/images/icons/facebook.png" alt="facebook" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Find us on facebook">`

```
 $(function () {
   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
     animation: 'fade'
   });
})
```

By default it is fade, but when I use some animation on it it dose not work.

I have tried to use [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) but same issue occurred.

```
 $(function () {
   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
     animation: 'animated slideInDown'
   });
})
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The tooptip is not generated until you hover the element. You need to add the respective class from animate.css after tooltip is shown.

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on('shown.bs.tooltip', function () {
        $('.tooltip').addClass('animated swing');
    })
})
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/czfnkkdj/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Options can be passed via data attributes or JavaScript. For data attributes, append the option name to `data-`, as in `data-animation=""`.

-- You need to care about bootstarp documentation [from here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) that `Apply a CSS fade transition to the tooltip` not a **class** like `animated slideInDown`.
By the way it's an boolean type.

[animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) is suggesting you to add classes for the elements, you want animated.

So you need to add some extra jquery like :

```
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').hover(function (){
          $(this).next().addClass("animated shake");               
    });
```