# Animated Bootstrap tooltip - problems with transform property

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip

I use **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074362/how-to-add-animation-on-bootstrap-tooltip)** solution to animate Bootstrap tooltip, but there is a problem. I would like to use scale transform on tooltip. When I hover over the button for the very first time it is working good, but then tooltip moves to different position. I think it is related to Bootstrap JS positioning of the tooltip (initially tooltip has scale 0 so dimensions of the tooltip are 0x0px and probably this is the reason of my issue).

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">Tooltip on bottom</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
.scale {
  animation: scale 200ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
```

JS:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on('shown.bs.tooltip', function () {
  $('.tooltip').addClass('scale');
});
```

### **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMRLmK)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I resolved my problem:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">Tooltip on bottom</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.scale {
  animation: scale 200ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
.tooltip.fade {
  transition: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on('shown.bs.tooltip', function () {
  $('.tooltip').addClass('scale').css('opacity', 1);
});
```

### **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEOPPB)**